# Calling to a method inside public method with this pointer

Tags: javascript, module

I'm using the next syntax for private/public  methods in `JavaScript`:

```
function Cars() {
    this.carModel = "";
    this.getCarModel = function () { return this.carModel; }
    this.alertModel = function () {alert (this.getCarModel());}
}
```

But when I'm calling to a method `alertModel` its having errors because `this` is pointing to the `window` object thus cannot find it: 
`alert (this.getCarModel());` - `this` pointing to window

```
var newObject = new Cars();
newObject.alertModel();
```

I tried declaring those method in `prototype` also, but it's acts the same.

```
Cars.prototype.getCarModel = function () {
    this.getCarModel = function () { return this.carModel; }
}
Cars.prototype.alertModel = function () {
alert (this.getCarModel());
}
```

What I'a doing is calling it without this `like` that:

```
  Cars.prototype.alertModel = function () {
    alert (newObject.getCarModel());
    }
```

Is it the only way? because in others methods its works.

Comment: Both answers are off topic. You must be mistaken. In your example, `this` is the instance (`newObject`) so it should alert the empty string as the value of `carModel`.

Comment: @ Marcell Fülöp This is the behavior when I calling it from different pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function Cars() {
    this.carModel = "";
    this.getCarModel = function () { return this.carModel; }
    this.alertModel = function () {alert (this.getCarModel());}

    return {
     getCarModel: getCarModel,
     alertModel: alertModel
    }
}

var newObject = new Cars();
newObject.alertModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've essentially declared free-floating functions inside of a scope.
You need to understand the difference between Scope and Context in Javascript. Interestingly, [Pragmatic Coffeescript](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) offers a good discussion on this. [This is another good resource](http://clubajax.org/javascript-scope-and-context-not-the-same-thing/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Cars() {
    var carModel = "";
    this.getCarModel = function() { return carModel; };
    this.alertCarModel = function() { alert (carModel) };
}
```

This way carModel will be private and cannot be accessed publicly, only by the alertCarModel and getCarModel methods.